# Doctrine: move Entity between Collections w/ unique constraint & cascade delete

Tags: collections, orm, doctrine

Given entity Car with a collection of Wheels:

```
@var Collection<Wheel>
@ORM\ManyToMany(cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
@ORM\JoinTable(
    joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(unique=true, onDelete="CASCADE")}
)
```

There's a unique constraint preventing a Wheels being attached to two Cars, and cascade deletion and orphan removal is enabled (when Car gets deleted, its Wheels will also be deleted).

The Job is to transfer a Wheel from one Car to another.
Since the Wheel doesn't know of its relation to Car (there are reasons for it, the example is simplified), you cannot update a Wheel but instead have to update the two Cars.

First try:

- Remove the wheel from the first Car
- Attach it to the second Car
- Update the first Car
- Update the second Car

Third step deletes the Wheel. Bad.

Second try:

- Remove the wheel from the first Car
- Attach it to the second Car
- Update the second Car
- Update the first Car

Third step violates the unique constraint. Bad.

I can't think of a way to transfer the Wheel. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would try it without the orphanRemoval, it doesn't seem to be necessary since you're using cascade delete. And also - why ManyToMany and not OneToMany?

Comment: Since the Wheels are in another package I cannot control, i have to use a ManyToMany relation. It's the only way to implement the relation without touching the Wheels.
How would removing the orphanRemoval help me here?

Comment: I believe it's orphanRemoval that is deleting the wheel in third step. As described in the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal):

*When using the orphanRemoval=true option Doctrine makes the assumption that the entities are privately owned and will NOT be reused by other entities. If you neglect this assumption your entities will get deleted by Doctrine even if you assigned the orphaned entity to another one.*